# Image annotation software for ML purpose

Tags: gratis, open-source, annotation

**Objective**: A software where the user can annotate an image with bounding boxes.
These annotations would be used for an ML algorithm like YOLO/R-CNN

Looking for an opensource, gratis software like [Brat](http://brat.nlplab.org/) which can be hosted on a server.

(Preferably Python-based)